# Timer not getting reset in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Hi I am getting problem in resetting the Timer control in C# win form application.

I am developing a simple countdown timer.

[image: Sample]

When I click on `start` it starts countdown from 59 seconds.
I need the timer should restart from beginning when I click on `Start` button.

code on `timer1_tick`

```
if (hours==0 && minutes==0 && seconds==0)
{
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 1;
    seconds = 0;
}
else
{
    if (seconds < 1)
    {
        seconds = 59;
        if (minutes == 0)
        {
            minutes = 59;
            if (hours != 0)
               hours -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            minutes -= 1;
        }
    }
    else
        seconds -= 1;

    lblTime.Text = hours + @":" + minutes + @":" + seconds;
}
```

and code on `btnStart_Click`

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Here I am trying to restart the `timer1`by enabling and disabling the `control` but it's not working.
I also tried to check with

```
timer1.Stop();
timer1.Start();
```

but it starts again from where it was stooped.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: BTW: I'd simply count from 0 to your initial timespan in seconds and display (initial - current) seconds on your form, so you don't need to "count" backwards, that would save a lot of code.

Comment: Use `TimeSpan` make life simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to store `DateTime` value which will represent target time (current time plus one minute):

```
// or DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
targetTime = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Then on each timer tick subtract current time from target time and display `TimeSpan` you will have:

```
var span = targetTime - DateTime.Now;

if (span.TotalSeconds > 0)
   lblTime.Text = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
else
   lblTime.Text = "Bingo!";
```

Thus you will not need to store and maintain three variables for hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
timer1.Dispose();
timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
```

To get rid of the object and re-initialise.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

in your  `btnStart_Click` you should reset  your instance  variables

```
hours=minutes=seconds=59
```

Comment: Might be my question is not clear but when my timer reach to 0 from 59 I have to do some work there and simultaneously have to show the countdown time too. So reassigning 59 value to all won't work

Answer (score 2):

Where are `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` defined?

It looks like your `btnStart_Click` simply needs to reset those values instead of resetting the timer.

I can't tell from your question what those default values should be though. You say the timer should countdown from 59 *seconds*, but then I see logic that's resetting minutes to 59 and other logic that decrements the hour (although the hour appears to start at 0 and never increase).

Comment: hours, minutes and seconds defined as global veriable and I am not going to increment the time I am decrements the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (timer1.Enabled) { timer1.Enabled = false; }
else { minutes = 1; seconds = 0; timer1.Enabled = true; }
```

if you want reset back to 1 minute, make this into your `btnStart_Click` function

note : for your `seconds` when it's become 0 it will be increase again to 59 although your `minutes` 0, you must validate it

```
if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
{
     timer1.Enabled = false;
     //this your code to reset variable hours, minutes, and seconds
}
```

use this function at function `timer1_tick()`